# firebase indexOn - I don't get it

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My database looks like

```
"spieler": {
    -Khlf0V8gsJ5wm49sdre {
       "vn":"Mike",
        .......
     },
    -Khlfkll0sJ5wm49sdre {
       "vn":"John",
        .......
     },
}
```

My rules:

```
{ 
"rules": {
  ".read": true,
  ".write": true,
  "spieler": {
      ".indexOn": ["vn"]  
    }
}
```

No matter what I am trying - John always follows Mike.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What you are trying to do? Do you know why we use .indexOn ?

Comment: Please show the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).